# How to generate a random arange in python?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a random arange of 10 values in Python. Here's my code. Is there any faster way or more elegant way to generate it ? Because the x in function **lambda** is actually never used.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random as rd
>>> i = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> noice = map(lambda x: rd.random(), i)
>>> i
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> noice
[0.040625208925370804, 0.3979391267477529, 0.36389993607597815, 0.5222540865995068, 0.4568532903714069, 0.9028000777629279, 0.6011546913245037, 0.4779160505869603, 0.9929389966510183, 0.7688424310182902]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `np.random.rand(10)`.

See the [NumpPy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).

Comment: You're very welcome, Mincong :) Please make sure to click the accept butten ^^

Comment: Of course, the accept button will be available in 8 min ;)